# Describing your problems in details

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, allah

Is there anything wrong if you converse with Allah for hours by explaining him your problems in the minimest detail. I mean explaining to him in the minimest details the passing blasphemest thoughts that cause you so much distress and anxiety. With the minimest details I mean being as detailed as you are with a genecologist when you have a serious and complicated gender illness. Of course you do it in a polite manner by saying that Allah is far from any imperfection or wrongdoing and it is enterily your fault that deserved this punishment or trial as a result of his sins

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's okay to do so.

It is the Sunnah of the Prophets to turn to Allah (ﷻ) with their troubles. Allah (ﷻ) mentioned that Prophet Yaqub عليه السلام said,  قال إنما أشكو بثي وحزني إلى الله وأعلم من الله ما لا تعلمون (He said, "I only complain of my suffering and my grief to Allah, and I know from Allah that which you do not know)- Qur'an 12:86. You can absolutely do the same, with proper etiquette which you mentioned already.

Regarding thoughts that give you distress and anxiety, these are waswasa (whispers) from Shaitan. Allah (ﷻ) said, وإما ينزغنك من الشيطان نزغ فاستعذ بالله إنه سميع عليم  (And if an evil suggestion comes to you from Satan, then seek refuge in Allah. Indeed, He is Hearing and Knowing) - Qur'an 7:200. Turning to Allah (ﷻ) in this case is actually the best response. So you're on the right track, MashaAllah.

As for an identity crisis, just remember that you are as you are created by Allah (ﷻ). You were created a human, so being confused as to whether you are meant to be an animal is illogical. Same goes for biological sex. He created two biological sexes and each sex comes with its own set of unique behaviors and Islamic rules to be followed. Accepting ourselves as we are created (destiny) is truly liberating.

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته